# Context.Provider to Link React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Im trying to provide a context to a "`<Link/>`" of react router which redirects to a component , but it only receive de default context.

How can I solve this?I´m using react router v6

Context.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext(null);

export { UserContext };
```

App.js

```
return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ teams, groupMatches, getImg }}>
      <>
        <div id="page-top">
          <Router>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
              <Route exact path={`/`} element={<Masthead />} />
 </Routes>
          </Router>
        </div>
      </>
    </UserContext.Provider>
```

Masthead.js

```
const { teams, groupMatches, getImg } = useContext(UserContext);
return userLogged && groupMatches ? (
    <>
      <UserContext.Provider
        value={{
          id: userLogged.id,
          userInfo: userLogged,
          teams,
          groupMatches,
          getImg,
        }}
      >
        <Navigation       
        />
      </UserContext.Provider>
```

Navigation.js

```
const { id, userInfo, teams, groupMatches, getImg } = useContext(UserContext);
<UserContext.Provider
        value={{
          id: userLogged.id,
          userInfo: userLogged,
          teams,
          groupMatches,
          getImg,
        }}
      >
 <Link to="/pronosticos"><a className="nav-link" /*href="#services"*/>Pronosticos</a> </Link>
</UserContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Basically, the <Pronosticos/> component does not receive the context I pass on the provider. It receives the default created context.

Comment: As per your given code, you're only passing the context to the link not the component. Context should ideally be used on the default <App /> component so that it can be accessed anywhere in the code..

Comment: yes, thats right. But I have some id that i get from a child component of App, so I have to pase a new value to the context

Comment: Please share your code in sandbox. type`react.new` in browser url and paste your code there

Comment: It's completely ***unclear*** what you are trying to accomplish here. You've wrapped/rendered *at least* three `UserContext.Provider` components in the provided code snippets. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? What is the use case or problem you are trying to solve for? What is the link linking to, there isn't any route for it? Please clarify what the issue is and what you are specifically asking for help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, since context provider is used on the  component, it can be accessed anywhere in the code.
And you shouldn't use user context provider on another components.

And what you should know is, even though you wrap the Link component with context.provider in Navigation component, the Pronosticos component cannot get it's values because the component isn't actually wrapped with the context provider.
So it will get the values of App context provider.

So please remove all context provider on all components except App.
And add id and userInfo values to the App context provider.
Next, in the useEffect hook of Masthead component, you can change context values.